# Calculate Mutual Information

Tags: information-theory

I have 2 events:

Event1 Event2

a           1

a           1

a           2

a           2

b           1

b           1

b           1

b           1

b           2

I want to calculate the mutual information between these 2 events. Here how I calculate it.

First I get the probability:
P(a) = 4/9 , P(b) = 5/9 , P(1) = 6/9 , P(2) = 3/9

Then the joint probability:

P(a,1) = 4/9 x 6/9 = 24/81

P(a,2) = 4/9 x 3/9 = 12/81

P(b,1) = 5/9 x 6/9 = 30/81

P(b,2) = 5/9 x 3/9 = 15/81

After that, I use the formula of Mutual Information:

MI(Event1, Event2) = 24/81 log (24/81 / 4/9 x 6/9) + 12/81 log (12/81 / 4/9 x 3/9) x 30/81 log (30/81 / 5/9 x 6/9) + 15/81 log (15/81 / 5/9 x 3/9)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

In particular, it seems that you are assuming $$P(a,1)=P(a)P(1)$$ which is not true.

Try to count how many $(a,1)$ occur to get an estimate of $P(a,1)$.

Remark: if we assume that $P(x,y)=P(x)P(y)$, the mutual information is equal to $0$.

Comment: So the joint probability is:
P(a,1) = 2/4                P(b,2)= 1/5
P(a,2) = 2/4              P(b,1)= 4/5
is that correct?

Comment: but what if I only given the probability? how to calculate the joint probability?

Comment: the joint distribution should sum up to $1$.

Comment: P(a,1) = 2/9 P(b,2)= 1/9 P(a,2) = 2/9 P(b,1)= 4/9 is that correct?

Comment: congratulations.